# Akka-Http WebSocket: handling incoming messages very slow

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I have a slightly modified example from [`akka-http` docs for WebSocket client-side](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/websocket-support.html):

```scala
package org.enso

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.{Done, NotUsed}
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws._
import akka.pattern.after

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Promise}

object SingleWebSocketRequest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
    implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
    import system.dispatcher

    // print each incoming text message
    val printSink: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] =
      Sink.foreach { _ =>
        println("foo")
      }

    val s1: Source[Message, NotUsed] =
      Source(Stream.fill(100){
        TextMessage("""{"method":"ping","responseSize":4}""")
      })

    // the Future[Done] is the materialized value of Sink.foreach
    // and it is completed when the stream completes
    val flow: Flow[Message, Message, Future[Done]] =
    Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat(printSink, s1)(Keep.left)

    // upgradeResponse is a Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse] that
    // completes or fails when the connection succeeds or fails
    // and closed is a Future[Done] representing the stream completion from above
    val (upgradeResponse, closed) =
    Http().singleWebSocketRequest(WebSocketRequest("ws://localhost:8080"), flow)

    val connected = upgradeResponse.map { upgrade =>
      // just like a regular http request we can access response status which is available via upgrade.response.status
      // status code 101 (Switching Protocols) indicates that server support WebSockets
      if (upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols) {
        Done
      } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(s"Connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}")
      }
    }

    // in a real application you would not side effect here
    // and handle errors more carefully
    connected.onComplete(println)

    closed.foreach {_ =>
      println("closed")
    }
  }
}
```

This code sends requests to a Websocket server-side, which works fine with another JS client. The server-side works fine, sending many responses at once, as evident from this Wireshark dump

```
E1@@ÿ   K^B!¹åª&
<·*<·#/{
  "response": "aaaa",
  "status": "success"
}/{
  "response": "aaaa",
  "status": "success"
}/{
  "response": "aaaa",
  "status": "success"
}/...
```

But printing "foo", which is the side effect of handling server messages in the Sink, only happens every ~5s, which is very slow compared with what is observed in Wireshark.

How would I explain / debug this? Could it be something to do with buffers / back pressure?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with this Sink everything works nice:

```scala
    val printSink: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] =
      Sink.foreachAsync(1) {
        case x: TextMessage => x.toStrict(FiniteDuration(100, "ms")).map { _ =>
          logger.debug("foo")
          receive = System.currentTimeMillis() :: receive
        }
      }
```

As it turns out, whenever working with akka – always consume all the input. This WS client API actually seems strange to me, for the http clients you get a helper method like discardResponseBytes precisely for this case. Anyway – consume the input, always

Comment: How would I debug this in the future? Any way to log the state of buffers, consumption, or backpropagation?

Comment: The `log` stage can be used to track the flow along the steam, but it doesn't tell of anything about the state of buffers and backpressure.